# CMOS Gates, I can't understand when we use those negation bubbles

Tags: digital-logic, cmos

I began to study CMOS gates, that are in my teacher's book, and I have 2 questions, because there is no explanation.

1. If we use NAND or NOR , it means we have F = ~(A*B) and F = ~(A+B) and is normal to have that little bubble (negation) at gates A and B right? [image]
2. What if we have function F = A(B+C) + D . Since is not ~(A(B+C) + D) , then why we have that negation bubble at A, B, C gates? Can someone explain please?

[image]

Comment: That bubble stands for PMOS transistor symbol.

Comment: aaa, it means positive MOS transistor right?

Comment: P channel MOS transistor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That bubble stands for P channel MOSFET transistor. See the following equivalent symbols.

[image: equivalent symbols]

See the picture for structure of a P channel MOSFET.
In CMOS technology the main substrate is P:

[image: CMOS PMOS]

For example in the NAND gate in  the question making both A and B HIGH will cause the upper transistors to be OFF and lower transistors to be ON, therefore  F is connected to the ground and will be LOW.

Comment: as I understand, that bubble will be always there because of P channel , and it won't depend if we have F = ~(A*B) or F = (A*B), right?

Comment: Technically the second image is a depletion-mode MOSFET, which is not commonly used.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes but their concepts are the same .

Comment: @ClaudiuM To create AND gates an additional inverter is required to convert NAND to AND. See [this link](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-3/cmos-gate-circuitry/)

Comment: To a point. Specifically to the point that DMOSFETs are normally *open*.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You're true, that was not a good image for the answer; I've removed it.